# Bubble sort using while loop. Last sort not present in the output

Tags: c#, sorting

I am attempting to create a bubble sort using while. I have posted my class below. Why in the sort the last int of 9 is not displayed.

```
namespace BubbleSort {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] i = {9, 2, 7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8};
            int va = 0, vb = 0;

            //loop through all numbers in the array.
            while (va < i.Length)
            {
                //loop through all numbers in the array trailing the first loop by 1.
                while (vb < i.Length)
                {
                    //compare the two values.
                    if (i[vb] < i[va]) {
                        Console.WriteLine(vb);
                    }                    
                    vb++; //increment
                }                 
                va++; //increment
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: Are you wanting to use bubble sort for a specific reason? Why not just i.OrderBy(x => x);

Comment: Thats not a bubble sort, additionally you are outputting the index and not the value.  Bubble sort involves multiple passes

Comment: i.Length is 9, you are incrementing an printing vb while it is less that i.Length, so you will never print out a 9.

Comment: Thats not a sorting algorithm, its just printing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No thats not a bubble sort, additionally you are outputting the index of the array and not the value.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) fo an explaination

You want something more like:

```
   int[] i = {9, 2, 7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8};
   int va = 0;

   bool swapped = true;

   while (swapped) {

     swapped=false;
     va = 0;
  //loop through all numbers in the array.
   while (va < i.Length -1)
   {
          //compare the two values.
           if (i[va] > i[va+1]) {

               int swap = i[va];
               i[va] = i[va+1];
               i[va+1] = swap;
               swapped=true;
           }

       //increment
       va++;  
   }
}
```

Then `i` will be sorted.

Btw this is sub optimal, you can use the nth pass optimisation and for loops for a better algorithm

A more optimised version with a for loop could be

```
int[] i = {9, 2, 7, 6, 1, 3, 5, 4, 8};

int n = i.Length -1;
bool swapped = true;

for (int n = i.Length - 1; swapped && n > 0; n--) {
  swapped = false;
  for (int va=0; va < n; va++) {
      if (i[va] > i[va+1]) {
           int swap = i[va];
           i[va] = i[va+1];
           i[va+1] = swap;
           swapped=true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You're not actually sorting anything. Here's what happens in your code:

- You set `va` and `vb` to zero and enter your two `while` loops
- The first iteration of the inner loop compares `i[0]` to each value in the array
- `i[vb] < i[va]` returns `false` for when `vb == 0` (because `9` is not less than `9`) so displays nothing
- `vb` is incremented
- the remainder of the inner loop completes. Since every other value in the array *is* less than 9, they all output a value, but the value you output is actually `vb` NOT a value from the array. Your loop goes from `0` to `8` and you skip the first value because it's the highest in the array - therefore you output numbers `1` to `8` in the inner loop.
- the inner loop completes with `vb` set to `9`
- your outer loop increments `va` and repeats
- `vb` is still set to `9` and so the inner loop is entirely skipped
- the above two steps repeat until `va` reaches 9, at which point the code completes.

If you use a different array as your input, you'll see that you get a totally different result. For example, if you remove the 9 from the front of the array, you only get `3` as an output (because only `i[3]` is less than the first value of `2`).  If you pad your array with three zero values, you'll actually get 9, 10 and 11 in the output, because you are outputting the counter/index value instead of the actual sorted value.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not.

1) Violation of the "S" principle: a class that implements bobble sort should not write to console.

http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

2) Your nested while loop only prints some numbers, it does not sort anything at all.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 0):

This is not bubble sort indeed. Bubble sort uses several passes, changing the positions of items in the list to be sorted. You just go through your list and pick out the smallets value at every loop.

To answer your question:

```
i[vb] < i[va]
```

i[0] is 9. It is *never* smaller than *any* of your other entries, so it *never* gets printed.

EDIT

Dang, yes. The *index* is being printed. Interestingly, i do not see vb being reset at any time to 0?? 
Well, let's say i am confused as to why anyone would think this is a sorting algorithm :)

Comment: Actually 9 is never printed because there are only 8 other entries in the array. If you padded the array with three zeroes, you'd get 9, 10 and 11 in the output.

Comment: Overlooked the fact the _index_ was printed indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1 ;  j< arr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                int tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", arr));
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a variation on a selection sort rather than a bubble?

Comment: Possibly, been like 10 years since I wrote any sorting algorithms :)